# Trigger javascript function or event inside a PDF

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, xfa

I'm trying to fill a `XFA PDF` using `JavaScript`/`Java`. The PDF is not made by me; I need to download it, fill it and upload back.

The PDF has a button for Import XML which does the work just fine, but I want to do it programmatically for my clients.

Is there any way to execute a JavaScript function inside the PDF or trigger the button event? I've tried to embed the `XML` as an attachment, but it doesn't trigger anything and the data is unchanged…

The PDF can be found here: https://mfinante.gov.ro/documents/2552173/2552377/02_F1103_Buget_individual_2022_07_07_A2.0.125.pdf/ee988bfb-b7bc-8774-29b5-95b0dc94df7e?t=1657200566548

And a XML example would be:

```
<f1103 d_rec="0" suma_control="18332934" luna_r="01" an="2025" nume_ip="dsadsadasd" cui_ip="17460640" special="0" tip_bug="I" an_apr="2025">
    <f1103_buget cod_sec_bug="02" cod_prog_bug="0000000000" cod_sfin="A" sect="F">
        <f1103_indicator cf_cap="11" cf_scap="05" cf_par="00" ce_titlu="00" ce_art="00" ce_alin="00" cb_an_0="12312" cb_an_1="124124" cb_an_2="423423" cb_an_3="123" cb_an_ult="312312" ca_an_0="0" limita_ca_an_0="0"/>
    </f1103_buget>
</f1103>
```